How do I redirect a request to another page?
route("/home") do

    s = GenieSession.session()
    if !GenieSession.isset(s, :userId)
        redirect(:login)

    end

end

This is a part of the main page of a web app and if the user is not logged in, the user should be redirected to the login page.
Based on the documentation that I found it should look something like this, but this just puts "Redirecting you to" into an empty html page.

How do you know the name of the route is :login? Have you manually set that? If not, it may be :get_login.
